# Local Cohomology of a coherent sheaf can be calculated with restricting the sheaf to the support?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes, local-cohomology

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a Noetherian Scheme . Let $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-module. Let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $X$. Let $Y:=Supp \mathcal F$, which is a closed subset of $X$.

Is it true that $H^j_Z(X,\mathcal F)\cong H^j_{Z\cap Y}(Y,\mathcal F|_Y),\forall j\ge 0$ ?  (of-course this is true when $X$ is affine ... )

If this is true, then is it also true that $\underline {H^j_Z}(\mathcal F)|_Y\cong \underline {H^j_{Z\cap Y}}(\mathcal F|_Y),\forall j\ge 0$ ?

(Here $\underline {H^j_Z}$ denotes the Sheaf of local Cohomology which is the sheaf associated to the pre-sheaf $U\to H^j_{Z\cap U}(U,\mathcal F|_U)$ , or equivalently it is the right derived functors of the left-exact functor from $Sh(X)$ to $Sh(X)$ which takes a sheaf $\mathcal G$ to the sheaf $U\to \Gamma_{Z\cap U}(U,\mathcal G|_U)$. For reference, see R. Hartshorne. Local Cohomology. A seminar given by A. Grothendieck, Harvard University. Fall, 1961. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 41. Springer, 1967. http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0073971 )

Comment: I assume $Y$ is the scheme theoretic support. Then, what you say is true, since $F$ and $F_{IY}$ are the same ( I am avoiding lower star).

Comment: @Mohan: What do you mean by scheme theoretic support ? Is it same as $\{ x \in X | \mathcal F_x \ne 0\}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the scheme with coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, let $i:Y \to X$ be the inclusion of the scheme-theoretic support and let $U$ be the open complement of $Z$. Then we know that $\mathcal{F} = i_{\ast} \mathcal{G}$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a coherent sheaf on $Y$.
We have long exact sequences $(A)$
$$
\cdots \to H^i_Z(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^i(U, \mathcal{F}) \to \cdots
$$
and $(B)$
$$
\cdots \to H^i_{Y \cap Z}(Y, \mathcal{F}) \to H^i(Y, \mathcal{F}) \to  H^i(U \cap Y) \to \cdots
$$
together with a map of long exact sequences$ (A) \to (B)$. Moreover we know that $H(X, \mathcal{F})=H(Y, \mathcal{G})$ and $H(U, \mathcal{F})=H(U \cap Y, \mathcal{G})$ and so we conclude that $H^i_Z(X, \mathcal{F})=H^i_{Y \cap Z}(Y, \mathcal{F})$ by the five-lemma.

Comment: Just to be sure, scheme theoretic support is the same thing as the set of points where the stalk is non-zero ... right ? (In which case I assume you're referring to something like Lemma 28.5.4 as here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JU ) ... also, why is there a long exact sequence (A) $\to $ (B) ?

Comment: The underlying topological space is indeed the support of $\mathcal{F}$ (where the stalks are nonzero), but the scheme structure might not be reduced. Affine locally it is given by the vanishing locus of the annihilator ideal of a module. The morphism of long exact sequences is just given by the various restriction maps (which are functorial by general nonsense).

Comment: Okay, thanks ... one question : why would the scheme structure on $Y$ matter ? Local Cohomology can be defined just for any topological space ... am I missing something ?

Comment: Did you take $\mathcal F|_Y$ to be $i^*(\mathcal F)$ ? If so , then of course the scheme structure on $Y$ does matter ... however, I originally meant $\mathcal F|_Y := i^{-1}(\mathcal F)$ (in which case, the scheme structure on $Y$ doesn't matter)  .... also could you please clarify why the respective sheaf-cohomology groups are isomorphic ? Thanks

Comment: Hello ... are you there ?

Comment: In general if $i:A \to B$ is a closed immersion of schemes (say Noetherian to be safe), then $H^i(A, \mathcal{F}) \cong H^i(B, i_{\ast} \mathcal{F})$.

Comment: I see , thanks ... and would you please spare to clarify whether you considered $\mathcal F|_Y$ as $i^*(\mathcal F)$ or $i^{-1}(\mathcal F)$ ?

Comment: The former, otherwise it will not be quasi-coherent sheaf and we cannot say anything.